# Vue and videojs: how reload video

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, video.js

In Vue (3) how can i reload the videojs?

I have the following code:

```
<template>
  <video-js controls="true" preload="auto" ref="video_player" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered">
  </video-js>
</template>


<script>

    import videojs from 'video.js'

    export default {
       data() {
         return {
          player: null
         };
       },


       mounted() {
          const element = this.$refs.video_player;
          console.log(element);

          this.player = videojs(element, {
             fluid: true,
             responsive: true,
             playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
             sources: [
             {
               src: 'url',
               type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
             }]
           })

</script>
```

The first time i call the component it works.

The second time, because the url is the same (change only the param id) the component is reused.
I need to force the component reload because videojs on dispose method destroy the dom.

So, how can i reuse the video player with vue js or force the component to re-render (so calling again creating and mounting)?

Thanks

Comment: In your `beforeRouteUpdate` try `this.player.src({ type: 'application/x-mpegURL', src: new_url });`

Comment: Is there any solution, I also want to play a new stream when the URL changes but it seems to be not working, and the player continuously shows a loading wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your component videoComponent

`<VideoComponent></VideoComponent>`

You can add key attribute to your component.

Thanks to that it will be re-rendered when key is changed

```
<VideoComponent :key="someUniqueParamId"></VideoComponent>
```